# How to debug connection issues caused by ufw/iptables?

Tags: 14.04, ufw

My current ufw setup is causing problems, specifically with git, and I suspect this will not be the last time it causes connection problems.

What should be the debug procedure to understand what/where the connectivity problem is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out the answer to my question and would like to share it.

First ensure that your ufw is creating logs.

```
sudo ufw logging low
```

Set up a terminal to observe the logs

```
tail -f /var/log/ufw.log
```

Execute the command that was previously causing an issue, for me this was with git.

```
git clone git@bitbucket.org:xxx/yyy.git
```

Check the log file, for me this caused a:

> Dec 16 14:05:12 *user* kernel: [16304.928083] [UFW BLOCK] IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=192.168.0.103 DST=131.103.20.167 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=47499 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=54885 DPT=22 WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0

Which tells me that an out connection to bitbucket was blocked by UFW, trying to access the destination ip of 131.103.20.167 via port 22.

Then creating an exception within UFW to solve this problem.

```
sudo ufw allow out to 131.103.20.167 port 22
```

There is a post on Ubuntu forms which explains how to read the UFW log file at: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2085110&p=12361050#post12361050